# How to handle "unsupported_grant_type" from laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, clientcredential

I'm playing around with laravel and try to enable client credentials grant to secure some api endpoints.

**To provide some context:** 
I want to create an api that stands between a database and several websites (and SPAs). So I'll be able to do some monitoring (what website/SPA calls which ressources) and in general add some security. So in this case where no additional user inforamtion is required, the client credential grant for machine-to-machine communication should be the best approach.

I followed someone tutorials (e.g. [this tutrial](https://filljoyner.com/2017/03/01/how-to-use-client-credentials-grant-tokens-for-your-api-authorization-with-laravel-5-4s-passport/)) to implement these grant type but I get stuck...

I did the following:

- load passport: `composer require laravel/passport`
- add service provider to `config/app.php`: `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,`
- migrate: `php artisan migrate`
- install: `php artisan passport:install`
- added `HasApiTokens` to `App\User.php`
- added `Passport::routes()` to `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`
- last but not least set driver option of the authentication guard to `passport` in `config/auth.php`

So far so good. Now I created a sample client with `php artisan passport:client`:

```
New client created successfully.
Client ID: 3
Client secret: S5s9oEIRm5DNy5ySsr1H6jWlraOCZyF24gcpoDrJ
```

Now when I want to get a token for this client by using postman (added in the `body.formdata` like provided [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-passport-client-credentials?page=1))
[image: postman: call oauth/token]

I get the following error.

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
}
```

Am I missing something? I thought I did all the necessary steps to register the `grant type`?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you @Kamlesh Paul... I searched your link for the client credential grant and it says `To retrieve a token using this grant type, make a request to the oauth/token endpoint:  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'client_id' => 'client-id', 'client_secret' => 'client-secret', 'scope' => 'your-scope', `. So the only think missing is the `scope` attribute. I tried this earlier and nothing changed if I provide this (I let it as an empty string, because I don't now what it really does)

Comment: Maybe its because you misspelled `grant_type`. In the screenshot it says `grand_type`

Comment: oh nooo :/ I'm so stupid. You're right @nahri, I changed it and it worked. Thanks!. 3 hrs lifetime wasted. Do you want to write it down as an answer, so that I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled `grant_type`. In the screenshot it says `grand_type`.

Answer (score 2):

The response is a bit late - but in case anyone has the issue in the future...

From the screenshot above - it seems that you are adding the url data (username, password, grant_type) to the header and not to the body element.

Clicking on the body tab, and then select "x-www-form-urlencoded" radio button, there should be a key-value list below that where you can enter the request data

Answer (score 0):

as you mention this is for SPA 
so

Try this

```js
grant_type: "password"
client_id:3
username:"your email"
password: "your password"
scope: "*"
```

put this in you postman

by this you will get `access token` and `refresh token` for that specif user

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kamlesh Paul. Unfortunately the error doesn't change... Why do I need to change the grant type? I mean later on the clients are no real users, instead they are SPAs and websites. So this is a machine-to-machine communication, right? Or did I miss misunderstood something?

Comment: OAuth is an open standard for access delegation, commonly used as a way for Internet users to grant websites or applications access to their information on other websites but without giving them the passwords  link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth